# Как объяснить появление отрицания в просьбе «Не могли бы Вы...»?

Tags: этимология, частица-не

Форма вежливой просьбы "Не могли бы Вы..." в русском языке содержит отрицание. Как объяснить его появление и какова его роль?

В других языках аналогичная просьба достаточно предсказуемо не содержит отрицания, например:

- "Could you please..." — в английском;
- "Könnten Sie..." — в немецком.

Особенно странно, что также возможно точно такую же просьбу корректно построить в форме "Могли бы Вы, пожалуйста..."

Answer (score 3):

1. Интересно то, что отрицание в русском языке встречается не только в просьбах вида  «вы не могли бы», но и **в обычных вопросах,** то есть  в этом явлении можно найти какой-то обобщенный смысл.

Прочитаем отрывок на эту тему из художественного текста (А. Барсенева «Нью-Йорк – Москва»),  из которого видно, как  **отрицание смущает  нерусских пользователей языка и вызывает непонимание.**

— И где ты встречаешь американский Новый год?

— Я еще не знаю, — улыбнулась Алиса. — Ты знаешь, я первый раз в жизни двадцать седьмого декабря не знаю, где буду встречать Новый год!

— А ты не хочешь встретить его со мной?

Алиса хорошо говорила по-русски, все в Москве удивлялись этому, будто невесть какому чуду, а у нее просто было хорошее языковое чутье, хорошая память на все, что происходило в детстве, и год общения с одним русским семейством в Нью-Йорке. Этого оказалось достаточно, чтобы понимать не только смысл того, что говорится по-русски, но и оттенки этого смысла. **И все-таки некоторые оттенки ставили ее в тупик — она не понимала их направленности. Зачем, например, спрашивать, что она не хочет сделать? Не проще ли спросить, что она хочет?**

— Ты предполагаешь, что я не хочу встречать с тобой Новый год? — на всякий случай уточнила она.

— Я не знаю.

— Я хочу, — кивнула Алиса. — Если ты меня пригласишь, то я обрадуюсь.

2. Смысл сказанного здесь понятен, его можно прочитать так. *Вероятно, у тебя много интересных предложений, поэтому, скорее всего,  ты не хочешь встретить Новый год со мной.* Фраза уклончивая, в ней нет прямого вопроса, она скорее о просьбе рассмотреть предложенный вариант среди других.
3. Что касается **модальных значений**, то они в русском языке легко трансформируются друг в друга, так что возможное легко превращается в желаемое, чуть ли не в требование, например:  *Ты мог бы мне и помочь!*  И даже отрицание не всегда смягчает фразу, если на помощь приходит ирония и соответствующая интонация: *Ты не мог бы мне помочь?!*
4. Итак, перед нами  вежливая фраза: ***Вы не могли бы мне помочь***? В действительности там такой подтекст:  *Конечно, вы так заняты,  я предполагаю, что вы не могли бы мне помочь, но может быть, все-таки уделите мне немного времени…*

Это  типичная **уступительная конструкция  ХОТЯ…НО**, когда **более вероятное уступает место менее вероятному**. Как я полагаю, смысл отрицательных вариантов именно в этом.

Comment: Согласен с 4-ым пунктом и заключительным выводом. По поводу 3-его пункта хочу добавить что двусмысленность "не мог бы ты мне помочь" легко обходится путем "не мог ли бы ты мне помочь". В то время как двусмысленность у "не могли бы вы мне помочь" обойти сложнее. Фраза  "не могли ли бы вы мне помочь" совершенно не разговорная из-за "двойного ли", но в письменном виде прекрасно смотрится. Но все таки с частицей не, двусмысленность почти не чувствуется так что и обходить её нет смысла.

Comment: Спасибо, интересное наблюдение, но мне кажется, что с частицей ЛИ проблемы и в устной, и в письменной речи.  В разговоре она произносится сложно, а на письме  отвлекает внимание от смысла, так как окончание путается с частицей.

Comment: @user190920 Посмотрите, пожалуйста, правила наращения (4-м, 3-го и т.п.).

Answer (score 2):

ПЕРВАЯ ВЕРСИЯ

> Могли бы вы помочь мне

Без должной вопросительной интонации может восприниматься как грубость, типа: "а ведь мог бы и помочь мне засранец". Но интонация ненадежный союзник, поэтому чтобы грубости не произошло ни в каком виде, вежливо спрашивают:

> Не могли бы вы помочь мне

Здесь даже в случае неправильного понимания - не получится грубости.

ВТОРАЯ ВЕРСИЯ

На форуме английского мне как-то говорили, что негативная постановка вопросов не равноценна позитивной. Типа в ней просят подтвердить предположение, в то время как в позитивной постановке спрашивают без каких либо предположений. Возможно и в русском языке имеется что-то подобное, какое-то заведомое предположение или смещенная вероятность ответа. Тогда "Вы не могли бы мне помочь" предполагает что вопрошающий считает что скорее всего человек не может помочь. Задавая такой вопрос, человек не ставит другого в неудобное положение на предмет отказа, тем самым проявляя свою вежливость. Ясно что просьбы типа "Вы не могли бы подбросить меня до центра" не имеют столько значимости как просьбы "Вы могли бы спасти меня?". Первые задаются в негативном ключе в угоду вежливости, вторые в позитивном в виду сильной нужды в положительном ответе.

Answer (score 1):

> Особенно странно, что также возможно точно такую же просьбу корректно построить в форме "Могли бы Вы, пожалуйста..."

А вот и нельзя! Можно спросить просто "Вы можете мне помочь?", но без сослагательного наклонения, которое без отрицания теряет смысл, и без "пожалуйста", которое характерно лишь для аналогичных просьб-вопросов в английском.

Прокомментирую также и на мысль Sharon из ответа мне на [другой вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464165/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B/464194#comment481801_464194) на ту же тему:

> ***«Не могли бы вы передать соль?»***
>
> В этой фразе есть прямое обращение к собеседнику. Однако на нее и подмывает ответить: «Нет, не мог бы!» Все потому, что фраза уже содержит заранее подготовленное пространство для отказа.

Я думаю, вы, Sharon, понимаете, как правильно, но где-то я встречал мысль, что некоторые понимают эту фразу буквально: "Вы действительно **не можете**?..", тогда как настоящий смысл "(Вы, наверно, не сможете, но) **не получится** ли так, что вы всё-таки сможете?.." На самом деле настолько буквально никто не понимает, это просто вежливая форма, но заложен в неё именно этот смысл.

Со следующим абзацем там согласен, но считаю, что отказать можно. Отказать вежливо: прости, но такие и такие дела, не могу. Без вранья, конечно. При условии хороших отношений между собеседниками подмывать сказать что-то резкое не должно, потому что другой тоже не будет искусственно, неискренне произносить эту фразу и постесняется лишний раз просить, если знает, что напряжёт этим товарища. А если кто-то тебя нагло использует и при этом фальшиво произносит эту вежливую фразу, то можно с чистой совестью сказать ироничное "Нет, не мог бы!" или "Не могу!", "Не лезь(-те) ко мне!", "Отстань(-те)!"

Answer (score 0):

"Могли бы вы, пожалуйста" - звучит грубее, и "пожалуйста" не делает выражение равнозначным выражению "не могли бы вы".