# "Могли бы вы..." вместо "Не могли бы вы..."

Tags: грамотная-речь, языковые-изменения

Мне сейчас позвонила под видом соцопроса девушка и спросила, ***мог бы*** я его пройти. Я осведомился, почему она спрашивает гипотетически вместо того, чтобы просто спросить, ***могу ли*** я его пройти. Теперь я подумал, что она хотела употребить выражение "Не могли бы вы...", но зачем-то опустила *не.*

*Что это происходит с языком? Готовы ли вы принимать такие изменения? Я нет!*

Answer (score 2):

Мне тоже не очень нравится такое обращение, но попробую найти "телефонное" объяснение его происхождению. Можно предположить, что подсознательно сотрудник колл-центра балансирует между подчеркнуто вежливым обращением "*не могли бы вы*" (воспринимается как просьба сделать *одолжение*, could/would you?) и фамильярным "можете..." (can/will you?). При обычной форме обращения собеседник может быстро закончить разговор, повесив трубку: какой-то аноним что-то просит. Вариант с сослагательным наклонением содержит *недоговорку*: "*могли бы вы [**если бы я попросил или предложил***]". При такой форме обращения сохраняется вежливость и отсутствует  "подобострастие", поэтому первая реакция абонента может оказаться не столь быстрой (он может колебаться - а вдруг предлагаемое и в его интересах?), и шансы, что он дослушает и даже согласится ответить, повышаются.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! И правда похоже, что балансирует он между этими вариантами. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен и дополнен

Я думаю, что правильной является только одна форма: ***Не могли бы вы пройти опрос?*** Это вежливая просьба,  условное устойчивое сочетание, именно так мы ее воспринимаем. Других возможностей у нас просто нет. В форме повелительного наклонения просьба  выглядела бы так:  Пройдите, пожалуйста,  опрос. Но это звучит навязчиво и несколько бесцеремонно.

А если убрать частицу НЕ и сказать: ***Могли бы вы пройти опрос?***  Устойчивость сочетания  нарушена, мы это фиксируем на слух и начинаем читать фразу **дословно.**

А в прямом смысле мы как бы интересуемся **реальными** возможностями  незнакомого человека – есть ли у него свободное время? Но это уже невежливо, почему он должен перед нами отчитываться?  Такой вопрос обоснован, к примеру, в следующей ситуации: ***Вы могли бы подъехать к нам завтра.*** Но здесь у  нас совместная заинтересованность во встрече, вот мы и спрашиваем.
Поэтому без  отрицания фраза выглядит некорректно.

Пояснение

1. Ваш вопрос, Артем,  меня немного развеселил, когда я решила поискать информацию по этой теме в Интернете. Попалась забавная статья, где автор **критикует обе формы  вежливой просьбы:** [https://psiholog.mirtesen.ru/blog/43200955936/«Mogu-li-ya»:-5-vezhlivyih-fraz-s-dvoynyim-dnom](https://psiholog.mirtesen.ru/blog/43200955936/%C2%ABMogu-li-ya%C2%BB:-5-vezhlivyih-fraz-s-dvoynyim-dnom)

Фраза ***«Могу ли я вас попросить закрыть дверь?»*** содержит вопросительную интонацию.
Столь сомнительный вопрос, который вы адресуете собеседнику, касается вас. Вы словно говорите: «Я настолько беспомощен, что не могу не только самостоятельно закрыть дверь, но даже сомневаюсь в своей способности озвучить просьбу».
Таким образом, перед собеседником буквально встает задача оценить ваши возможности, с ходу сообразить, достаточно ли вы крепки, чтобы обратиться к нему и в случае чего выдержать отказ.

***«Не могли бы вы передать соль?»***

В этой фразе есть прямое обращение к собеседнику. Однако на нее и подмывает ответить: «Нет, не мог бы!» Все потому, что фраза уже содержит заранее подготовленное пространство для отказа.

Люди слышат эту фразу примерно так: «Я, конечно, понимаю, что вам не до моей просьбы. Вы мне все равно откажете. Но попробовать стоит». Несмотря на мягкий тон фразы, фактически вы заранее слегка обвиняете собеседника в черствости. Такой речевой прием направлен на то, чтобы вызвать у собеседника чувство вины: «Ну как я могу отказать, я расстрою такого хорошего человека». Но зачастую на деле вызывает ответную агрессию: «Нет, не мог бы!»

2. Я не могу сказать, что согласна с таким толкованием – это просто **условные вежливые фразы**, не стоит читать их дословно, как это делает автор. Правильное оформление выглядит так: (1) Могу ли я вас попросить? Можно ли вас попросить? (Вы говорите о себе.) (2) Не могли бы вы это сделать? (Обращение к лицу.)
3. Подобный вопрос **уже обсуждался на форуме**, я там объясняла возможное  происхождение этих выражений  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462965/Как-объяснить-появление-отрицания-в-просьбе-Не-могли-бы-Вы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462965/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%92%D1%8B)
4. Но вот что мне не очень нравится в данных вам ответах. Почему мы ориентируемся на другие языки, неужели это именно **кальки  с английского?** А если даже и так, то когда эти формы появились у нас?  Кроме того, они вполне соответствуют внутренним законам нашей речи  – это общий принцип **взаимозаменяемости наклонений**, о чем я тоже уже говорила.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы стали гуглить по теме и нашли мой вопрос таким образом?! Если так, то очень забавно!))) Не очень понял, что значит "(1)". Но под этой цифрой же нету сослагательного наклонения...

Comment: Я в Сети нашла другой вопрос, а в статье просто обсуждается две вежливые формы, они разные по построению, но обе используются. А в вашем вопросе был переделанный вариант отрицательной формы, вот этот вариант неверный. Сослагательного наклонения в первой фразе действительно нет, но это не принципиально (ошибся автор). С другой стороны, существует корректная форма и при отсутствии отрицания, но нужно их правильно выбирать.

Comment: А как вы относитесь к первой фразе, может быть, она действительно избыточная с точки зрения вежливости.  Наверное, лучше сказать так : Можно вас попросить...

Comment: Ага, я бы и сказал "Можно вас попросить?.."

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, Вы, Артём, разбираетесь в английском лучше, чем я. Позволю себе высказать предположение о влиянии этого языка в такого рода вежливых вступлениях.

"***Could you...***" мы переводим как "***Не могли бы вы...***"
"***Couldn't you...***" – "***Разве вы не могли...***"
Но многие, не видя отрицания в первом случае, переводят дословно: "***Могли бы вы...***"
Лично я согласен с Вами и в своей речи использую старую устоявшуюся фразу.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Мне почему-то кажется, что те, кто так говорят (без отрицания), могут совсем не знать английского, а вот те, кто вставляет "пожалуйста", скорее всего, заимствуют это как раз из английского.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  А все мы живем в одной языковой среде.

Comment: Я только не понимаю, зачем такие люди буквально переводят с английского, если они воспитаны у нас и должны прекрасно знать, как у нас (по-русски) говорят в таких случаях.

Comment: Трудно представить себе весь процесс внедрения такого словосочетания, который может идти годами. Может, здесь еще имеет место так называемая экономия средств, стремление языка к простоте.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут объяснение простое. Обращение с использованием сослагательного наклонения звучит более вежливо.
Тут полная аналогия с английским: can — более грубо, could — более вежливо.

Почему она опустила «не» имеет чисто психологические причины.

Прочитайте отрывок из [Жванецкого](http://www.jvanetsky.ru/data/text/t7/utesovu/):

> — Что ты знаешь! Я не могу с ним ходить по магазинам, он им подсказывает ответ. «Скажите, пива нет?» Они говорят: «Нет». «А рыбы
> нет?» Они говорят: «Нет». Тридцать лет я с ним мучаюсь. Он газету не
> может купить. Он говорит: «Газет нет?» Они говорят: «Нет».

Люди зачастую не хотят общаться с такими людьми, как позвонившая вам девушка. Если она вам скажет: «Не могли бы вы…?», какой ответ просится сам собой? «Не могу!»

Но ведь её задача удержать вас на линии, ей нецелесообразно говорить такие вещи. Вот она и упустила «не».

Я думаю, что вас это насторожило, как человека разбирающегося в языке, а большинство людей бы это нормально восприняло: вежливо и без побуждения к отказу.

Comment: Не просится такого ответа, с "не" просто вежливая форма вопроса, а без — сослагательное наклонение, нелепое тут. И зря вы правите мой вопрос.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Кавычки лапки русском языке ставятся внутри кавычек ёлочек, если внутри кавычек, что-то ещё в кавычках. Лапки не ставятся первыми, как у вас. И лапки у вас не присущие русскому языку, а скорее английскому. Лапки в русском языке развёрнуты наружу, а не внутрь. Правильно: Он сказал: «Это лекарство „Фервекс“».

Comment: @Артём Луговой И в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) тоже так написано: В русском языке традиционно применяются французские «ёлочки», а для кавычек внутри кавычек и при письме от руки — немецкие „лапки“. Пример со вложенными кавычками: Правильно: «„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Вы же использовали английские двойные кавычки. Почему я зря исправил? Вы же не на английском писали.

Comment: Никакие не английские, это [компьютерные кавычки](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/89-kav). Они тоже вполне допустимы. Александры же тоже ставят их, посмотрите. Если все тут будут ставить исключительно ёлочки, я тоже стану, но фактически-то ставят их реже. А знак препинания часто принято делать таким же, как и предыдущий текст, смотрите Розенталя, Грамоту.

Comment: @Артём Луговой По вашей ссылке: «"компьютерные кавычки" ­– кавычки особого типа, в которых **рисунок открывающих и закрывающих кавычек совершенно не различается**. Такие кавычки встречаются в текстах, набранных на компьютерной клавиатуре». Посмотрите не свои кавыки, отличается ли рисунок открывающих и закрывающих кавычек? Явно отличается: “”. А у так называемых компьютерных не отличается: "". У вас английские кавычки. «А знак препинания часто принято делать таким же, как и предыдущий текст, смотрите Розенталя, Грамоту» — это я вообще не понял, можно пример.

Comment: @Артём Луговой «Если все тут будут ставить исключительно ёлочки, я тоже стану, но фактически-то ставят их реже» — это аналогично «Если все перестанут бухать, то я тоже перестану, а пока хоть кто-то бухает, я то же буду, пока не сопьюсь». Что за изобретение Грамоты.ру компьютерные кавычки, мне не известно. Обратите внимание, что Word заменят их автоматически на ёлочки.

Comment: Я говорил про точку после курсива. У меня именно компьютерные кавычки, а не такие, как вы нарисовали.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Насчёт точки не знаю, надо вопрос изучить. Я понимаю так, что точка — это часть основного предложения, курсивом выделяется слово для того, чтоб выделить его — визуально отделить от основного текста. Зачем выделать точку?

Comment: @Артём Луговой Я не пойму вот что: когда исправляют мои вопросы в целях улучшить и сделать более правильными, я это расцениваю как хорошие поступки и не пытаюсь доказать, что я на самом дела был прав и не отменяю изменения, если они верные. Почему вы потратили время для того, чтоб изменить кавычки обратно на английские? Это конечно ваше дело, но мне хотелось бы понимать на будущее логику таких действий, чтоб тоже не тратить время понапрасну на улучшения чужих вопросов.

Comment: *Зачем выделять точку?* Так смотрится лучше. Я не менял обратно кавычки, я просто не принял вашей правки, но там ещё один человек должен рассмотреть эту правку. Курсив хочу оставить в своём стиле, а кавычки можно и такие, но тогда не будет единообразия с моими другими вопросами, ответами и комментариями.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Насчёт того, что смотрится лучше согласен. Точка, конечно, мало отличается, а запятая контрастирует, если слово и запятая написаны разным начертанием.

Comment: Рад, что согласились!))

Comment: К чему это вы? «Рад, что согласились!))» Всё началось с того, что вы не согласились с исправлением кавычек.

Comment: Я про предыдущий ваш комментарий.